finding option id of single select field in github projects by using `gh` cli
I want to update a single select field by using gh command. However, the problem is to find single-select-option-id
gh project item-edit --id $id              \
    --single-select-option-id <option-id>  \
    --field-id $field_id                   \
    --project-id $project_id




variable
source
result




$id
gh project item-list 
✔️


$field_id
gh project field-list
✔️


<option-id>
❓
✖️



I couldn't manage to fetch the id of this single select field. Is there a solution for this?
